# how to plot a dot with longitude and latitude in a floor map image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, maps, imagemap

I am working on an app where I get coordinate from GPS location using Cordova. I have a floor map image now I want to plot a dot in the floor map image. How can I calibrate floor map to display where the dot goes. Help would really be appreciated .

Comment: What's the exact problem? Do you know the GPS coordinates of the map corners? The rest is basic interpolation.

Comment: How to give the GPS coordinates to floor map corners. so I can show a dot which   already have a GPS coordinate on the floor map image @ChrisG

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, no need to explain it again. If you have the coordinates of the corners, say lng1 and lng2 for the X direction, then `x = (lng - lng1) * width / (lng2 - lng1)` where `width` is the map width.

Comment: You mean let's say I have a floor map image of an office with width & height X & Y, and I have four GPS coordinates(lng1, lat1 && lng2, lat2) for the image. And again I have a GPS coordinate of Dot(lng3, lat3). How can I show that dot in the Map. @ChrisG

Comment: Possibly to _"have a floor map"_ is not enough for your purpose (that I've perfectly understood, thanks in advance) . The floor is existing in the real world? In such case there is a correspondence between the points in the floor and the points in the map and you have to apply the same correspondence to go from the GPS position —in the real world— and the position of the point you want to draw in the map of the floor.  ፨ If the floor doesn't exist in the real word your question, as currently posed, is meaningless.

Comment: Floor exist in real world. how can I give correspondence point to a image map now. @gboffi

Comment: You should use for the GPS point the same geographical projection that you, or someone else, used to draw the floor map.  I hope that you understand that neither I nor someone else on SO could know which mapping was used... ⍨ If I'm permitted to give advice, if you don't know what I'm talking about it's time to step back and learn, on your own, something about geographical projections aka _map_ projections.

Comment: Why are you still asking how to do this *after I specifically told you how to do it*? If you don't understand the math, why not say so? Why do you keep asking "how can I show the dot" instead of acting like a normal human being...? I used `lng` for the dot's longitude. Did you miss that? Why not ask about the formula? Why ask questions as if my comments didn't exist...??